# Probability of the limit of random variables

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of random variables with domain $\Omega$ and codomain $E$. Limits of measurable functions exist, so $\lim_{i} X_i$ is makes sense. In general, do we have for any open set $S \subset E$

$$P(\lim_{i}X_i \in S) = \lim_{i}P(X_i \in S)?$$

I couldn't come up with a proof nor a counterexample. If it is incorrect, what are some counterexamples, and is it correct at least for a certain family of sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does make sense to speak about $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} X_i\,$, however, that limit need not always exist.

- Example: $X_i=W_i$ where $W$ is a one- or two-dimensional (hence [recurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process)) Brownian motion. If $W$ is a higher dimensional BM the limit does not exist either because every component of $W$ is a one-dimensional BM.

As a counter example to

$$
\mathbb P\Big\{\lim_{i\to\infty} X_i\text{ exists and is in }S\Big\}=\lim_{i\to\infty}\mathbb P\Big\{X_i\in S\Big\}
$$
we take again a Brownian motion $W$ in $\mathbb R$ and $S$ the open interval $(-1,1)$ and let $\tau$ be the exit time of that interval when $W_0=0$. Let
$$
X_i=W_{\textstyle\tau-\frac{1}{i}}\,.
$$
Since $W$ has continuous sample paths we have with probability one $\{W_\tau=-1\text{ or }W_\tau=1\}.$ That is,
$$
\mathbb P\Big\{\lim_{i\to\infty} X_i\text{ exists and is in }S\Big\}=0.
$$
On the other hand it is clear that every $\mathbb P\{X_i\in (-1,1)\}$ is one because $\tau-\frac{1}{i}<\tau$.

Comment: Could you please explain why your first example has no limit? Let's say the Brownian motion is on $\mathbb{R}$. Is it because if the limit existed to be X, $P(X \in \mathbb{R})$ would be $0$ by countably additivity of measures? - Also, are there important families of sequences where $P$ and $\lim$ do commute?

Comment: The non existence of the limit $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}W_t$ for one- or two-dimensional Brownian motion follows from the [recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process) of $W$. An important family to look at might be the martingales in [Doob's first convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems#Doob's_first_martingale_convergence_theorem). Without further context I have little incentive to find out if $P$ and lim commute.